# Publishing SWF using Adobe Flash

Tags: adobe, flash, publishing, using

I have a SWF file which contains of an image (1keyframe) and also, it contains an AS3 file with the following codes:

```
var loader:Loader=new Loader();
var ur:URLRequest=new URLRequest("1.swf");
loader.load(ur);
addChild(loader);
```

I am trying to play the swf file (1.swf - an audio) while the image is being displayed. What I want to know is how will I be able to publish this project into an SWF file which can still play as expected even without the raw 1.swf file. I can publish SWF right now but when I delete the 1.swf file, my generated swf can only display the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to host your file 1.swf at an actual URL, you could change your AS3 code to fetch the file, over the network, from that specific URL.

Comment: yes i can actually do it. but what i want is to totally embed the file into the new SWF file so that i won't be needing the 1.swf file anymore. Is there any possible way to do this?